# How do you pass an Object to the home screen widget?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-widget

---

This is my first time asking a question on SO.

I want to pass my Calculation object to the widget to be displayed on the home screen. I have the widget to update in my MainActivity.java when I click the calculate button:

I'm using Parceler.

[Here is my widget after clicking the Calculate button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KqaH.jpg)

[And the MainActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMzEu.jpg)

My issue is that the widget is not displaying the calculation info that was supposedly passed to it from the Provider class. it seems to parcelize correctly in my logs that display the calculation, just that I may be setting the widget view incorrectly to receive the data and display it.

```
public void saveCalcInfo(View v){
     
     [...]
     
     setWidget(calculation);
}


private void setWidget(Calculation calculationToPassToWidget) {
     BullAppWidgetProvider.manualUpdateWidgets(getApplicationContext(), calculationToPassToWidget);
}
```

### All I really need from the widget is to receive the calculation info, and display it.

A nice to have would be upon clicking the button "View", launch the MainActivity and autofill the EditTexts with the displayed information about the calculation

### Here's my BullAppWidgetProvider.java

```
public class BullAppWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

     static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId, Calculation calculation) {
          RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_provider);

          if (calculation != null) {
               views.setTextViewText(R.id.symbol, calculation.getSymbol());
               views.setTextViewText(R.id.shares, String.valueOf(calculation.getShares()));
               views.setTextViewText(R.id.buy, String.valueOf(calculation.getBuy()));
               views.setTextViewText(R.id.sell, String.valueOf(calculation.getSell()));
               views.setTextViewText(R.id.comm, String.valueOf(calculation.getComm()));
          }

          Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, appWidgetId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

          views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.viewCalcBT, pendingIntent);
          views.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_app_title, context.getString(R.string.widget_prompt));

          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
     }

     static void manualUpdateWidgets(Context context, Calculation calculation) {
          ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(context, BullAppWidgetProvider.class);
          Timber.w("Calculation received in manual Update: %s", calculation.toString());
          AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
          int[] appWidgetIds = manager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);

          for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
               updateAppWidget(context, manager, appWidgetId, calculation);
               Toast.makeText(context, "Widget has updated!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
     }

     @Override
     public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
          for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
               updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId, null);
          }
     }
}
```

If needed, here's the

### widget_layout.xml

file for reference

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/primary">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/symbol"
        style="@style/AdapterStyle"
        android:text="@string/ipl" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shares"
        style="@style/AdapterStyle"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/_42" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/buy"
        style="@style/AdapterStyle"
        android:layout_below="@id/symbol"
        android:text="@string/buy" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sell"
        style="@style/AdapterStyle"
        android:layout_below="@id/buy"
        android:text="@string/sell" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comm"
        style="@style/AdapterStyle"
        android:layout_below="@id/shares"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/comm" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewCalcBT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/sell"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/view" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

as well as the

### widget_provider.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widget_app_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <
        android:id="@+id/ll_parent_for_widget"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the response. I edited and hopefully clarified my issue. Let me know if it needs to be broken down further. I just don't exactly know where the point of failure is at this time.

Comment: I only really want one item in the widget that gets overwritten upon clicking calculate, which uses the widget_layout formatting. But the template layout only started showing up once I started using the ListView in the widget_provider.xml.

Comment: To respond to your message about storage, I'm using Firebase Firestore Database to save the calculations to cloud, and then recall them in the lower RecyclerView in the MainActivity >populate the EditTexts in the upper portion. I have no idea how to retrieve them to a widget in this case (or if that would be easier) but passing them manually from activity is how I'm trying to do it for now.

Comment: Yeah, gotcha, just stick with getting that working, first. It's much easier, but there's a lot of unnecessary stuff, then. You can get rid of the `RemoteViewService`/`BullWidgetItemFactory`, and its `<service>` element. Also remove the remote `Adapter` setup from `BullAppWidgetProvider`. Then replace the `<ListView>` in `widget_provider` with the `<RelativeLayout>` from `widget_layout`, which you can then delete. I'm not sure what `WidgetAppService` is for yet, but we don't need it now. The general update stuff looks OK, but it'll be easier to see where it's off after everything's trimmed.

Comment: Good point. So in my project, I'm removing the whole RemoteViewService class, the manifest tag, delete setRemoteAdapter. Should I edit the question with the stuff you suggested so you can see it easier?

Comment: WidgetAppService is the service class handling broadcasts of the Parcelized calculation object from the Activity. Not sure if that helps with this.

Comment: Understood, and changes made. So since the `Activity` is trying to pass the `Calculation` directly, `WidgetAppService` isn't used. Is that where the object passing disconnect occurs? How should I be implementing the `WidgetAppService` in this case?

Comment: I don't really think you need `WidgetAppService` at all, unless I'm not understanding what you mean for it to do, eventually. You're passing the `Calculation` directly in the `manualUpdateWidgets()` call. From there, its values go directly on the `RemoteViews`. Anyhoo, along with the layout changes I suggested, this is what the Provider ends up like: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CxmJvB7VmjJS4SpMpH4rBt6Vm50jEzhi/view?usp=drivesdk. I threw all this into a quick test project, and it works as expected.

Comment: Okay, good to know about the `WidgetAppService`. Now, when I run the app with your Provider class, and `RemoteViewService` removed, the widget layout (template) does not appear at all. I uninstalled, ran a couple logs, the calculation is being passed appropriately, but I get an empty widget with just the header TextView being set appropriately.

Comment: Did you replace the `<ListView>` in `widget_provider` with the whole `<RelativeLayout>`, and its children, from `widget_layout` (which we're no longer using)? You're basically combining those into one layout.

Comment: I now understand what you mean and Implemented the swap out. It works perfectly. Mike, you're an absolute legend. Thank you for all your help. You've been instrumental in getting me out of this 2 week rut with my project.

Comment: No problem! Sorry that wasn't clear, initially. I should mention that this probably isn't exactly how you'll want to do this for the final product. If you were to reboot, for example, all of those values would go back to the XML defaults. You're going to want to persist those values to storage, somehow, and have your `AppWidgetProvider` pull from that. The `Activity`'s button would really only be triggering an update, after storing. For these few values, `SharedPreferences` would be just fine. Hopefully, though, this has helped to see how this all works, and what needs to be modified. Cheers!